# How to use Cookies from 1 test into all other tests in API automation using RestAssured and Cucumber

Tags: api, automation, cucumber, rest-assured

In scenario 1 i am running a API. On successful response, i get 2 cookies.

Now these cookies i need to reuse as an authentication in all other tests. Can you please suggest me a way to do this?

Currently i am using setContext() and getContext(). This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways

1. Use a DI container like Spring or Pico
2. Use Scenario Context